# FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING) on line number 12?

Tags: php, html

I'm quite new to php and trying to test my php script online and came across 'FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'is' (T_STRING) on line number 12'. What can be done to fix this error? I'm trying to test the php online so I can work out how to add payment apis.

The PHP

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  
class Processing extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
        if($this->session->userdata("userID") == "")
        {
          $this->session->set_flashdata("processloginredirect",1);
         redirect(base_url());
        exit;
        }  
    }
    public function index()
```

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: Maybe you have a space in one of your `$this` ... judging by the mess that is your sample code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: sorry - if($this->session->userdata("userID") == "")

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that line.

Comment: thanks i thought so - when i got to test it using PHPTESTER online getting this error

Comment: there's a brace missing for this and/or code

Comment: @Lewis Can you post a link to the phptester page with your code?

Comment: can you explain more? thanks in advance @FunkFortyNiner and will try to do that now barman

Answer (score 0):

I've had really odd errors like this before.  You may have an invisible character or unicode lookalike on that line.  Try this:

Select `$this` on that line.

Delete it.

Re-type it manually.  (No copy / paste.)

Comment: Well then either there's an 'is' on that line, or you're looking in the wrong file.